# Server side validation in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, server-side

I am trying to do a server side validation that blocks "^$/()|?+[]{}><" metacharacters
Anyone give me some insight on why this .
I am new to this :/   (TextBox3 is a asp textboxe that takes input)

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Partial Class Default2
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If Regex.IsMatch(TextBox3.Text, "^$\/()|?+[]{}><") Then
        Label1.Text = "Invalid input"

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

ERROR:

```
 Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: parsing "^$\/()|?+[]{}><" - Unterminated     [] set.
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Also, what is `form1` referring to?

Comment: Why are you using `form1.InnerText`? What do you expect that will return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the string `^$\/()|?+[]{}><` is regex metacharacters. You need to escape them before passing to the regex function:

```
    If Regex.IsMatch(TextBox3.Text, Regex.Escape("^$\/()|?+[]{}><")) Then
        Label1.Text = "Invalid input"
    End If
```

UPDATED ANSWER:

2 methods to check if the text contains any of the regex metacharacters:

**Method 1: Using Regex**

The metacharacters need to be put inside a character class `[...]`. Therefore, only some of the characters need to be escaped, ie: `^`, `\` and `]`.

```
    If Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, "[\^$\\/()|?+[\]{}><]") Then
        ' Invalid input
    Else
        ' Valid
    End If
```

**Method 2: Using `IndexOfAny` String function**

This method doesn't use Regex so, there is no need to escape.

```
    If TextBox1.Text.IndexOfAny("^$\/()|?+[]{}><".ToCharArray) > -1 Then
        ' Invalid input
    Else
        ' Valid
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you ajakblackgoat,  DO you know why my Label1 isn't showing "Invalid Input" when I put one of those characters in Textbox3?

Comment: That's because the input text must match the exact regex pattern. I have edited my answer above to include two methods to do the validation.